# Access route param in express middleware invocation

Tags: express, middleware

I have an application which uses Discord to authenticate users. On the backend, on certain endpoints I need to check whether the user making the request is admin in a given guild.

E.g.: `PATCH "/set-bot-config-for-guild/:guildId"`,   <- I would like to allow only server admins to call this

I have created an authentication middleware. It is a function that returns a RequestHandler function, like so:

```
export function authenticateAdmin(guildId: string) {
   return async (req: Request; res: Response; next: NextFunction) => {
      // get user auth token from req.cookies.token
      ...
      // verify token with Discord auth api, get user id
      ...
      // get user roles in given guild, from Discord api
      ...
      // get admin role id of given guild from Discord api using guildId
      ...
      // check if user has admin role in given guild
      ...
      if (userIsAdminInGuild) {
         next()
      }
      else {
          return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
      }
   }
}
```

Originally I wanted to call this middleware like so:

```
router.patch(
   "/set-bot-config-for-guild/:guildId",
   authenticateAdmin(guildId),
   async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
       ...
   }
);
```

The problem is, that `guildId` comes from the route param `:guildId`, to which I don't have access yet when calling the middleware.

- Is there any way to get it and pass it to the middleware?
- Or do I need to just get the guildId in the middleware function itself? Because maybe guildId won't always be in the route but coming from somewhere else, and I'd still like to be able to use this middleware.

**Edit**: after some more investigation, it turns out I can't access `req.params.guildId` in the middleware either. So I will just have to write a function that checks if user is admin in a given guild and call it in any relevant route handler.

It works, but if anyone has a more 'elegant' solution, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `guildId` in the middleware itself.

Define the route like this

```
router.patch(
   "/set-bot-config-for-guild/:guildId",
   authenticateAdmin,
   async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
       ...
   }
);
```

And in the middleware you will have the `request` properties if you define it as function.

```
export const authenticateAdmin=async (req: Request; res: Response; next: NextFunction) => {
       const guildId=req.params?.guildId;   
       // get user auth token from req.cookies.token
       ...
       // verify token with Discord auth api, get user id
       ...
       // get user roles in given guild, from Discord api
       ...
       // get admin role id of given guild from Discord api using guildId
       ...
       // check if user has admin role in given guild
       ...
       if (userIsAdminInGuild) {
          next()
       }
       else {
           return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
       }
    }
```